# How to create batch file for updating the directories path in Tool->Option->Projects and Solutions in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, visual-c++, command-line-arguments

How to create batch file for updating the directories path in Tool->Option->Projects and Solutions ?

I want to update the following directories path,

Executable Files,
Include Files,
Library Files,
Source Files

Could you please let me know how to create a batch file for the same or share me if there any existing batch file is there for same purpose?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Sree

Comment: These options haven't existed since 2008. They were bad options and that's why they were removed. First consider not using those options. There are frequently better ways to do whatever you need doing. If you insist, then you must say which VS version you're using. After that, ask google where the settings are stored for that version or set them to memorable values and search your hard disk for those values. Next, ask google how to edit a file by command line. Try using sed and regexes. But also, stop using those options. They're no good.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I need to create batch file for all VS versions.

Comment: You can't create a batch file for all VS versions since the option does not exist in all VS versions. Think about why you want to do this, and solve the problem in an entirely different way. And anyway, if you want to create a batch file for all VS versions where this option exists: repeat what I said for each VS version. There are only a finite number.